# How do I appeal a denial of a Spanish Student visa, when no reason was given for the denial?

Tags: visa-refusals, spanish-language

My wife and I submitted student visa requests to the Spanish Consulate in Chicago. We wanted to go to language school in Madrid. We met all of the visa requirements, including making full payment for each of us for 21 weeks of school.  We provided all of the requested documentation, including the necessary means to support ourselves, insurance including repatriation, etc.

When submitting our visa requests, we were told that they would probably be rejected because we had to speak Spanish to obtain the visa.  Since this is ridiculous, we went ahead and submitted our requests.  After two weeks, our passports were returned to us with a letter stating that our requests were denied, but with no reason.  When we questioned the person who gave us the letter, he simply shrugged.

I am 68 years old and my wife is 66.  I suspect that they simply did not believe that we were planning to attend language school, even though we submitted proof of payment.  I got the language school on the phone, but the consulate would not talk to them.

How can we appeal and what new information might we provide to assist in our appeal?

Comment: Did you use an agency/agent or apply directly? According to the consulate in Miami, [the requirements](http://www.exteriores.gob.es/Consulados/MIAMI/en/InformacionParaExtranjeros/Pages/Visa%20Requirements/Student-Visa.aspx) do not include paying any money but do require an acceptance letter. Of course, a visa is only required for an accredited school recognized by the government.

Comment: (the requirements for this visa are the same regardless of consulate, but Miami had better documentation than [Chicago](http://www.exteriores.gob.es/Consulados/CHICAGO/en/ServiciosConsulares/consularservicesinchicago/visas/Pages/inicio.aspx) in this instance)

Comment: The OP says this is for a 21 week study. That's less than 5 months. How is that long term?? Short term study is one of those things you do as a tourist not an expat.